# Otimização de Múltiplos POST via Ajax

Tags: jquery, laravel-4, laravel, jquery-ui

Eu tenho uma pequena aplicação, e fui construindo ela conforme fui conhecendo o Laravel, então hoje em dia tem coisas que vejo que estão erradas e procuro adequar às boas práticas de programação e um dos pontos-chave são as intermináveis inclusões no db, via ajax.

Bom para entenderem melhor a estrutura da aplicação é a seguinte:

- O sistema é um grande banco de referências de texto, video, imagem, url, são entradas numa coluna do banco de dados;
- O sistema possibilita uma reordenação dos itens, usando a função `sortable` do jQueryUI;
- A grande questão é, atualmente tenho 448 entradas (ordenadas por id decrescente) e se por exemplo eu quiser definir que a última entrada que fiz, ex: #449, seja a primeira a ser exibida (no caso ordem:0), preciso mapear e mandar um post re-mapeando todas as outras entradas...

Minha principais dúvidas, são:

- Como posso enviar as index atualizadas num post só, aliviando o DB?
- Como gerar uma resposta depois que a lista for atualizada?

Vou postar apenas a função de update e a função do ajax, caso precisem de mais infos posto aqui.

```php
//Controller
public
function updateOrdem() {
    $entries = $this->entrada->orderBy('ordem', 'ASC')->get();
    $itemID = Input::get('itemID');
    $itemPos = Input::get('itemPos');
    foreach($entries as $entry) {
        return DB::table('entradas')->where('id', '=', $itemID)->update(array('ordem' => $itemPos));
    }
}
```

```js
//AJAX
$('#entradas ul').sortable({
    revert: true,
    cancel: "#entradas ul li span, .modal",
    stop: function (e, ui) {
        $.map($(this).find('li'), function (el) {
            var itemID = el.id
            var itemPos = $(el).index();
            console.log('pos' + itemPos);
            console.log('id' + itemID);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "updateOrdem",
                data: {
                    itemID: itemID,
                    itemPos: itemPos
                },
                dataType: 'html',
                done: function () {
                    console.log('ok');
                }
            });
        });
    }
});
```

http://laravel.io/bin/MXE8

Answer (score 1):

Para ter apenas um POST, utilize o .ajaxSuccess e dispare o callback por ele.

```
    $(document).ajaxSuccess(function() {

        $('#entradas ul').sortable({
            revert: true,
            cancel: "#entradas ul li span, .modal",
            stop: function (e, ui) {
                $.map($(this).find('li'), function (el) {
                    var itemID = el.id
                    var itemPos = $(el).index();
                    console.log('pos' + itemPos);
                    console.log('id' + itemID);
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "updateOrdem",
                        data: {
                            itemID: itemID,
                            itemPos: itemPos
                        },
                        dataType: 'html',
                        done: function () {
                            console.log('ok');
                        }
                    });
                });
            }
        });
$( ".log" ).text( "O callback dispara aqui: " );
});
```

Agora com relação ao Loop que faz para inserir no DB, a única forma que vejo seria enviar um json com todos os valores e depois fazer uma função usando o .extract_json_value (caso seja MySql).

Como você está utilizando o Eloquent, não sei se seria legal ficar usando function... mas não vejo outra saída.

P.S: Não testei nada... é apenas uma sugestão.

Comment: Eu testei o .ajaxSuccess, no ambiente local que tenho apenas 7 entradas e ele está retornando múltiplas respostas também (as 7 no caso), além disso no load da página ele já está inserindo os callbacks (estranhamente no load ele insere 9 callbacks)

Comment: Você já tentou chamar o sortable totalmente vazio? Ex: `$('#elemento').sortable({ stop: function() { console.log('stop'); } });` e  `$('#elemento').sortable({ stop: function() { console.log('stop'); } });` . Dá uma olhada se ele dispara esses callbacks.